# Symbol issue with the newpxmath package

Tags: beamer, fonts, symbols

I have a problem with the `newpxmath` package, which I would like to use in `beamer` for a presentation.

The symbol appearing when I use `\bar{}` is wrong.

For example with the simple code `g\to q\bar{q}` I get the result shown in the image below.

[image: with the newpxmath package]

However when I remove the package, and compile without `newpxmath`, I get the correct output

[image: without the newpxmath package]

Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue ?

The following code gives rise to the problem described above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$g\to q\bar{q}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I do not get this problem.  There must be an issue with interactions with other (unspecified) packages or else something is out of date.  Please provide an MWE so that we can compare.

Comment: In my own MWE, if I put `\usepackage{newpxmath}` before `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I do not get the error. If I put newpxmath after fontenc I do get the error. But we need to see your code to understand the problem.

Comment: I've posted an MWE that gives rise to the problem the OP mentions. I'm conjecturing that it's actually the `newpxtext` package rather than the `newpxmath` package that's causing the problem: If `newpxtext` is *not* loaded, i.e., if only `newpxmath` is loaded, the math mode font problem does not seem to arise.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your input. To put things in context, I am using the beamer template Stockholm available here :
https://www.overleaf.com/2081728vjjnkb
The problem however only seems to appear because of the newpxmath/newpxtext packages that are called, which is why I didn't mention the template in the original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell `beamer` that you want to use custom fonts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    $g\to q\bar{q}$
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: bar again]